# Python Split CSV cells into rows and save as new file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV structured like this:

```
Title,Url,Sku
MMHTF-PNB-1,http://localhost:52119/docs/openaccessprovider/default-document-library,160 | 168 | 171 | 162
```

And I'd like to split the sku cell at the pipe into new rows and have the existing title and url data to flow down.

I can get the code to `print` as I'd like it, but I cannot get it to save as a new CSV. Any suggestions?

```
import csv

with open('sfexport.csv') as f:
  f.readline() 
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
  for line_list in csv_reader:

  sku_list = [x.strip() for x in line_list[2].split('|')]
  for sku in sku_list:

    print sku +','+ line_list[0] +','+line_list[1]
```

Comment: You don't have a `writer` object. Where were you trying to write to a file?

Comment: You're right. I completely missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @roganjoshn pointed out, I missed the writer object.

Answer (score -1):

When writing to the csv are you getting any error messages that you can share with us?  Perhaps any permission errors, etc?

Also, I don't see any writer objects in the code.  Refer to the csv documentation here for more information on writing.

https://realpython.com/python-csv/#writing-csv-files-with-csv